# Is $ \int_0 ^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ an improper integral, even though substituting $u=\sqrt{x}$ turns it into the proper $\frac12\int_0^1du$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Here is the question,

> Is $\;\int_0 ^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}\;$ an improper integral?

Of course, that integral is improper because of discontinuity at $x=0$. Nevertheless, after the substitution $u = \sqrt x$ then $du = \dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt x}$.

Therefore, integral turns out to be
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_0 ^1 du$$
However, that integral is not improper yet.

$$ \displaystyle \int_0 ^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}= \frac{1}{2}\int_0 ^1 du$$

Is there a something wrong or can we generalize that if we have improper integral that converges can turn out to be integral which is not improper?

Comment: Yes, this integral in improper, but you can calculate it explicitly. Everything is ok :)

Comment: There’s nothing wrong about this situation. It certainly can happen that an improper integral is turned into a proper one after substitution. In fact, in the case where the improperness comes from discontinuity, you can always do this by substitution $u = F(x)$ where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 x^{-\alpha} dx$ will converge for $\alpha < 1$, and diverge for $\alpha \ge 1$.

Comment: This integral is an improper integral indeed. The way you usually find its value is to restrict the domain of integration and then make the domain tend to the original one. In fact, with Riemann integrals, this is how you define the quantity you are interested in. With Lebesgue integrals, the definition is a bit different, but the method to calculate the value still works because of the Beppo Levi theorem. Nevertheless, double check that all the hypotheses of the variable swap theorem are satisfied, and if not, restrict the support.

Comment: To help see that there's no paradox here, consider this analogue: $\frac46$ is an improper fraction, but we can turn it into a proper fraction $\frac23$ by dividing both the numerator and denominator by $2$.